# GoogleCredential.FromFile stuck and throw exception

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform

I have a strange issue:

```
if (_Credential is null && OsEnvironment.IsLocal)
{
   _Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(path);
}
return _Credential;
```

this code in my local PC stuck and after some time throw exception but in another computer (virtual computer) it run ok:

```
The type initializer for 'System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyLite' threw an exception.
StackTrace:    at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyLite.ImportKeyBlob(String blobType, ReadOnlySpan`1 keyBlob, Boolean en
crypted, ReadOnlySpan`1 password)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.ImportKeyBlob(Byte[] rsaBlob, Boolean includePrivate)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.ImportParameters(RSAParameters parameters)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer.FromPrivateKey(String privateKey)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateServiceAccountCredentialFromParameters(JsonCredentialParameters credentialPara
meters)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialFromParameters(JsonCredentialParameters credentialParameters)

   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialFromStream(Stream stream)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.FromStream(Stream stream)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.FromFile(String path)
   at Irony.Anaconda.Helpers.CredentialManager.GetCredential(String path) in
```

one more things is that it dont work in my PC as console app (work great as webapi)

work with Google.Cloud.SecretManager.V1 1.5.0

Is anyone know how to fix it ?

Comment: Easy, don't use a service account key file on your computer! Use ADC instead!

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? (And what *exactly* happens when you try to use it as a console application?)